# Cron python script not executing

Tags: python, cron, smtplib

I  have read a few posts on this but I could not find help in them.

I have a python script that sends mail using smtplib. It works when invoked from the command line.

I have `#!/usr/bin/python` as the first row and can run it both using `/home/pi/ipsender.py` and `python /home/pi/ipsender.py`.

My crontab is `*/1 * * * * /home/pi/ipsender.py` but I have also tried `*/1 * * * * python /home/pi/ipsender.py` and `*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/ipsender.py`.

Doing `which python` I get `/usr/bin/pyhton` and running python from the command line I can import and use smtplib just fine.

In `/var/log/syslog` I get:

```
Nov 27 22:57:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[3764]: (pi) CMD (python /home/pi/ipsender.py)
Nov 27 22:57:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[3763]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

And I'm guessing the No MTA... is just about Cron not sending emails about what it's doing, or isn't it?

How do I run this script.

[Edit]

The permission of the script is

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi   pi       551 Nov 27 22:37 ipsender.py
```

[Edit2]
Using the tip from D Read I'm getting the following log

```
starting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/ipsender.py", line 7, in <module>
    ifconfig_output = sp.check_output(["ifconfig", "wwan0"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Suggesting to me that there is something with the path. Although in `/etc/crontab` I have `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` and `which ifconfig` gives `/sbin/ifconfig`. So that should not be a problem right?

Comment: What is the permission of the file?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 pi   pi       551 Nov 27 22:37 ipsender.py

Comment: If you try "sudo su", and then run the script manually, does it work?

Comment: Are you running in crontab from the same user as you tried in shell? Ensure that rights and environment are the same in both cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of gotchas with crons... In the absence of the MTA, see the output an easier way - try piping it to a file:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/pi/ipsender.py > /home/pi/ipsender.log 2>&1
```

Start your python file off with a `print 'starting'` to see if the python file starts to execute ok.

Comment: Well, I can see the script failing [Edit2] but I can't figure out why.

Comment: Your script is run from the `pi` user's crontab which runs in a different shell to `/etc/crontab`. I think if you put the `PATH=` line in the same crontab as your script it might work. Alternatively try specifying an absolute path to `ifconfig` in your script.

Answer (score 1):

Try to save the STDOUT and STDERR of the script:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/pi/ipsender.py &> /tmp/ipsender.log
```