# How to fix wmctrl Cannot open display when Python open subprocess

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, wmctrl

This is my program, and it works very well.

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output("wmctrl  -l",shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
result = result.decode('UTF-8')
print(result)
```

Output:

```
0x03800003 -1 name-PC Desktop

0x03e00037  0 name-PC How to fix wmctrl Cannot open display when Python open subprocess - Stack 
Overflow - Firefox

0x05000006  0 name-PC name@name-PC: ~

0x05a00001  0 name-PC pr.py — ~/Program — Atom

0x05001c85  0 name-PC Terminal
```

But if I want to run this program at startup as root in Linux Mint I have problems. I want to run this py file at startup as root but I don't know how to do it. The main question is how to do it.

This is my attempt to solve the problem. It does not work.

I added a file `pr.service` to folder `/etc/systemd/system/`:

```
[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/pr.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I created a file pr.sh in folder `/usr/local/bin/`:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/python3  '/home/name/Program/pr.py'
```

I used these commands:

```
sudo chmod 744 /usr/local/bin/pr.sh
sudo chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/pr.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable pr.service
```

If I run my program with command

```
systemctl start pr.service
```

I can see this error with command

```
sudo journalctl -u    pr.service
```

I have an error command subprocess.CalledProcess Error: Command 'wmctrl -l' returned non-zero exit status 1.

I can change my py file, for example I can run

```
result = subprocess.check_output("/usr/bin/wmctrl  -l",shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

I can change my py file to see error:

```
import subprocess
try:
    result = subprocess.check_output("/usr/bin/wmctrl -l -p",shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    result = result.decode('UTF-8')
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    raise RuntimeError("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output))
print(result)
```

RuntimeError: command '/usr/bin/wmctrl -l -p' return with error (code 1): b'Cannot open display.

I have read about this attempt to find solution: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-automatically-execute-shell-script-at-startup-boot-on-systemd-linux

This is an article how to autorun script in Linux as root. I did these things.

My main goal is to autostart my program as root:

```
import subprocess
try:
    result = subprocess.check_output("/usr/bin/wmctrl -l -p",shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    result = result.decode('UTF-8')
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    raise RuntimeError("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output))
print(result)
```

You don't need to find mistake in my solution. It will be interesting to find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find solution myself. The key is to use two commands:

```
os.system("xhost local:root &>/dev/null")
```

allow root opening X windows.
And

```
 subprocess.check_output([command], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).decode('UTF-8')
command = "env DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/ourname/.Xauthority "+"wmctrl -l -p -lp"
```

allow root to read our settings.

So we can rewrite our program.

```
import subprocess
import gc
import time
prf = ["env", "DISPLAY=:0",   "XAUTHORITY=/home/ourname/.Xauthority"]
while True:
    r1 = subprocess.run(['xhost', 'local:root'],stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL )
    r2 = subprocess.run([prf[0], prf[1], prf[2],"wmctrl", "-l", "-p", "-lp"],  encoding='utf-8', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    if r1.returncode == 0 and r1.returncode == 0:
        print("Now we will not have problem with display error")
        break
    time.sleep(3)
while True:
    r1 = subprocess.run([prf[0], prf[1], prf[2],"wmctrl", "-l", "-p", "-lp"],  encoding='utf-8', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in r1.stdout.split('\n'):
        print(line)
    time.sleep(3) 
    gc.collect()
```

Comment: `[command], shell=True` is wrong; you want either `command, shell=True` where `command` is a string for the shell to parse, or `[commandname, arg1, arg2,...]` without `shell=True`  where each member of the list is an (unquoted) string.

Comment: But my program works. I'm using it today. It's fine. This code works.

Comment: That doesn't mean it will work correctly on other platforms, or continue to work across a Python upgrade.

Comment: Also, while mixing `os.system` with `subprocess` is harmless, it's inelegant; you might prefer `subprocess.check_call(["xhost", "local:root"], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)`

Comment: For Python 3.5+ you should prefer `subprocess.run` but perhaps your code needs to support older versions of Python?

Comment: Thank your for your information about subprocess.run. I changed my answer with subprocess.run.

Answer (score 0):

Te error "Cannot open display." also caused me trouble. This is how I could resolve it on Linux Mint 20.3 - only the DISPLAY code needed to be different from @ddd777's answer. The xhost part was not necessary.

```
user = 'yourusername'
env = dict(DISPLAY = ':0.0', XAUTHORITY = f'/home/{user}/.Xauthority')

def get(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(['/bin/bash', '-c',  cmd], env=env
                                   ).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is the error I was getting on Ubuntu 22.04. I was trying to use cron to run a python script.

```
Cannot open display.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usera/Applications/auto_close_old_nautilus_windows.py", line 55, in <module>
    wlist1 = [l.strip() for l in get(["wmctrl", "-lp"]).splitlines() if nautpid in l]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
```

These 2 solutions worked for me.

**Solution 1**

Run

```
crontab -e
```

Use `export` to export the `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` variables. Note that a backslash is required prior to the equal symbol(`XAUTHORITY\=`).

```
# /tmp/crontab.kCWtBN/crontab
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# [...]
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/1 * * * * export DISPLAY=:1 && export XAUTHORITY\=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority && python3 /home/usera/Applications/auto_close_old_nautilus_windows.py >>/home/usera/Applications/script.log 2>>/hom>
```

`CTRL+X` and `Y` to save your edits.

This should work. Below is what my python script had.

```
# auto_close_old_nautilus_windows.py - Note I do not pass in env=
subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()
```

**Solution 2**

In your python script, specify the DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY variables and pass them in with the env argument.

```
env = dict(DISPLAY = ':1', XAUTHORITY = f'/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority')
subprocess.check_output(cmd, env=env).decode("utf-8").strip()
```

**How were the DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY variables obtained?**

Add these 2 lines (os.environ.get) to your script.

```
# auto_close_old_nautilus_windows.py
# ...
# other code in script

print(os.environ.get("DISPLAY"))
print(os.environ.get("XAUTHORITY"))

# other code in script
# ...
```

Run your script.

```
python3 auto_close_old_nautilus_windows.py
```

The script works and you get this output.

```
:1
/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
```

The DISPLAY variable is `:1` and the XAUTHORITY is `/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority`. Your output will be different.

**Why is the error happening to begin with?**

When cron executes your script, DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY are not set. The 2 solutions I mention configure DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY before cron executes your python script.

**References**

1. [Cron not working with python subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319849/cron-not-working-with-python-subprocess)
2. [How to make Crontab run a Python script that opens the Terminal and does stuff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54805988/how-to-make-crontab-run-a-python-script-that-opens-the-terminal-and-does-stuff)